# SVN backup all the repositories in one go

Tags: svn, backup

I've seen lots of ways to backup a single repository in subversion. Is there any way to backup all the repositories in one go. I have lots of repositories for different projects and don't want to have to create a script every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured all repositories to use the fsfs backend, then you can use regular file-based backup tools (such as tar, dump, rsync, ...).

If you use bsddb repositories, I recommend to convert them to fsfs, with a svndump/restore cycle.

Answer (score 6):

A single repository in Subversion is the largest unit of storage that is managed within Subversion itself. Separate repositories are just different directories, each containing one repository.

If you already have a script to back up a single repository, then you can set up that script to take the repository name/path as a parameter. Then, you could write a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for repo in /home/repositories/*; do
    backup-single-repository $repo
done
```